# Connect Server Manager to a new independent domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019, windows-server-core

I'm currently testing a new domain controller on Server 2019 Core. Bit late to this but it's my first time actually trying to achieve anything on Core so every single step is a hurdle. Just setting the IP address requires a google search...

At this point I have a domain controller set up, which wasn't too difficult, but I am now stuck at connecting to actually do anything with it.

My workstation is currently in our main company domain and I'd ideally like to avoid having to mess about creating trust relationships, etc, just to play with a system I may scrap and rebuild multiple times.

Server Manager just gets as far as "Online - Access Denied" when using the domain administrator account.

I could probably set up a windows 10 vm and log it onto the new domain as administrator, but is there no straight forward way I can get management access to this test machine otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that simply adding a local hosts entry for the full dns name (`server.ad.mydomain.net`), then using that during add was enough to get it to connect. Not sure how that fixes an access denied error...

Still get an error trying to run computer management but it looks like I can do the majority of what I need to. Everything directly from server manager and all the AD tools seem to work.